# Lenovo tablet stuck on a screen with Chinese letters

Tags: lenovo

My Lenovo tablet, the new version, was dead and so I turned on my tablet accidentally using the volume button. When it turned on, I saw a bunch of Chinese-looking letters and I accidentally pressed an option, but now it’s stuck like that. I don’t know what to do, it won’t let me turn on or off. Volume button or anything won’t help.

I did a Google scan to translate what it says and it means “Speaker resistance correction.” I don’t know what to do.

Is it just going to be stuck like that?

Comment: Normally the last menu entry is "Exit" or something like that. You can also try to press and hold power for up to one minute.

Comment: Possibly related/duplicate: [Strange chinese menu on Lenovo IdeaTab S6000](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/63806/44325)